# Options to solve JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I validate a site using Google's Page Speed and I get the following error:

```
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Your page has 1 blocking script resources and 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

I have two javascript files on bottom of my page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/main?v=5jyyqQNx45M0Mbw-ZD6J9SVac8LfWyZZLh_wq6HtfQI1" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

I am getting JQuery from Google CDN and Main.js from local server.

I applied async to Main.js but this does not solve it ...

... The only thing that solves this is adding async also to JQuery from Google's CDN.

But then the code in Main.js using JQuery stops working ... No idea why.

**CSS**

I am not sure what to do to solve it. Any suggestion?

Could someone, please, help me out?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: `But then the code in Main.js using JQuery stops working` This is because "`main.js`" starts downloading and invoking before `jquery.min.js` has finished downloading/invoking. Do these two script tags appear immediately before `</body>`?

Comment: Yes, they both appear just before </body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then the code in Main.js using JQuery stops working ... No idea why.

That code breaks, because jQuery is loaded after Main.js is executed and as Main.js depends on it .. well, it's going to fail.

You won't come around loading your CSS and JS, therefore there isn't really anything you could do - Except using pure HTML.

The [linked google help page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) says:

- If your CSS/JS file is quite small, then load it using inline tags
- You can try to put important CSS/JS in one file and not-so-important one in another file which is loaded async

Comment: That was what I was considering: bundle the JQuery into Main and load everything async ... I will not use the CDN but it will all be in one single request ... About CSS what Google suggests makes no sense to me ... It even will cause more requests and really hard to maintain code

Comment: @MDMoura Yes, but the CSS which is not required directly is loaded after the user already sees the page and therefore gives it time and gives the user a faster feedback.

Comment: For the CSS: Google suggests to put CSS code directly into the head. Thats really stupid, not only for maintaining, but also because the user has to load this css for every page!